# Is there a 32-bit version of Floating Sandbox?

Tags: floating-sandbox

*Floating Sandbox* is a PC game where you have all these tools and can destroy a ship, and I want to play it, but there is one problem. I have 32-bit Windows 7, but I only know of downloads for the 64-bit version. I want to know if there is a 32-bit version or a way to make the 64-bit version compatible with 32-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is an Indie project, and only released only a couple of months ago, *if* they intended there to be a 32-bit version, it has not yet been released, and would still be working on it.

However, there's no way to tell without talking to them directly about it.

And unfortunately, there is no tool that can allow you to run this in a 32-bit environment; without hacking up the program in some way itself.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no 32-bit version at this moment. The game is a physics simulation and it's quite hungry for CPU resources; for this reason, the source code tries to take advantage of all possible performance improvements available on modern low-end CPUs, such as SSE vectorization and data packed in 64-bit words.

Building the game for 32-bit platforms not only would require considerable effort on our side, but it would also not yield a satisfying user experience - the simulation would very likely lag to the point of being unusable.